# Reshaping array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

How can I reshape an `(4,n,m)` sized numpy array to an `(n*m,4)` array?

The motivation comes from working with images, where I would like to create a matrix where the rows contain the RGBA values of each pixel. I tried `np.array.reshape(n*m,4)` but it does not do the job. Maybe in combination with `movaxis` or `swapaxis`?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

especially provide input, desired output and your attempt at coding a solution.

Comment: You need to `swapaxes` or `transpose` first, so the shape is (n,m,4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to reshape it to `(4, n*m)` first, then just swap the first and last axis (for example using [`transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) or simply the `.T` attribute):

```
arr = arr.reshape(4, n*m).T   # assuming your array is called "arr"
```

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> n, m = 20, 30
>>> arr = np.arange(4*n*m).reshape(4, n, m)
>>> arr = arr.reshape(4, n*m).T
>>> arr
array([[   0,  600, 1200, 1800],
       [   1,  601, 1201, 1801],
       [   2,  602, 1202, 1802],
       ..., 
       [ 597, 1197, 1797, 2397],
       [ 598, 1198, 1798, 2398],
       [ 599, 1199, 1799, 2399]])
```

Comment: `arr.transpose(1,2,0)` might be better than default `(2,1,0)`.

Comment: @hpaulj At the time of the `transpose` the array is only 2D.